# Plane in SceneKit ios not showing up

Tags: ios, objective-c, scenekit

I am trying to create a plane in using Scenekit in ios, but nothing is showing up for me. Just a blank screen. Here is the code i wrote in view did load.

```
SCNView *scnView = (SCNView*)self.view;
scnView.scene = scene;

cameraNode.camera = [SCNCamera camera];
[scene.rootNode addChildNode:cameraNode];
scnView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true;

SCNMaterial *greenMaterial = [SCNMaterial material];
greenMaterial.diffuse.contents = [UIColor greenColor];
SCNPlane *plane = [SCNPlane planeWithWidth:1.0 height:1.0];
SCNNode *planeNode = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:plane];
planeNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
[scene.rootNode addChildNode:planeNode];
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: the default `position` of `SCNNode` is `(0,0,0)` – which happens to be the position of `planeNode`. You'll need to set `cameraNode.position` to something like `(0,0,3)` to see something from that camera.